# Is it possible to remove Gwent mods without starting a new game?

Tags: the-witcher-3

I've added a Gwent mod (specifically, Gwent Redux) but after playing with it for a while, I decided I don't like it.  However, when I remove the mod, I lose all my cards.  **Is there any way to get original Gwent back**, without restarting the game?

I tried adding the original cards with console commands, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much research, it seems that this is unfortunately impossible :(